# Why is it implying I'm dividing by zero?

Tags: java, if-statement, divide-by-zero, arithmeticexception

I'm solving a few exercises from HackerRank.com and the code works perfectly on Netbeans and even in the page compiler for test cases, but when I submit the code it throws me this error in every test(except the last):

> ArithmeticException: thrown at Solution.main(Solution.java:15)

Here's the code:

```
     Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
     int a = s.nextInt(),j=1;
     for(int i=0; i<a; i++){
         int b = s.nextInt(), c =s.nextInt();
         for(j = b*c; j>0;j--) {
         if((b*c)%(j*j)==0){
             System.out.println(b*c/(j*j));
             break;}
         } 
     }
```

Line 15 is:

```
    if((b*c)%(j*j)==0){
```

What's wrong with the statement? 
I've set 'j' to be different from 0 in the for loop, so no reason for dividing by zero, which was the only explanation I could find by myself.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Many conditions besides divide-by-zero can trigger an ArithmeticException. An operation that results in an imaginary number, for instance, or an integer overflow. If you're sure it's not a div0, chances are it's an overflow.

Comment: may be you got `0` when insert value from s.nextInt()

Comment: Don't you get ahy other information form the exception??

Comment: Overflow? You have a divisor of `j` squared, which could possibly result in zero value.

Comment: They don't show the test cases, but I believe that they don't insert 0, because it is supposed to be a length measure. And there's no other information, that's all it says.

Comment: it's an overflow problem i think when u put b*j it's possibly to overflow the range of integer. i test this 1
123123123
123123123
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
 at test.Test.main(Test.java:15)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `b*c` is large, `j` will eventually equal <strike>`2147418112`</strike> `65536` (=2<sup>16</sup>) and `j*j` will be `0` (remember, Java `ints` are always 32-bits). Performing `%` when the divisor is `0` results in your `ArithmeticException`. Note that any multiple of `65536` will cause this error. The `2147418112` (=2<sup>31</sup>-2<sup>16</sup>) originally referenced above is just the largest multiple that will fit in an `int`.

Example code (you can run it yourself at http://ideone.com/iiKloY):

```
public class Main
{ 
     public static void main(String []args)
     {
        // show that all multiples of 65536 yeild 0 when squared
        for(int j = Integer.MIN_VALUE; j <= Integer.MAX_VALUE - 65536; j += 65536)
        {
            if((j*j) != 0)
            {
                System.out.println(j + "^2 != 0");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Done!");
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right! I would never think about 'int' properties. Thank you!

Comment: @Bobby Thanks. Note that I made a mistake, the real limit is 2^16 (or 65536), which should have been obvious to me from the start. Guess I need to go to bed :)

Comment: No problem, I got what you meant. =]

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing an overflow.
Try the following input, and you can get the ArithmeticException.

```
1
256 256
```